# How to select first select option after filtering in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a `select` with filter. After filtering Angular loses the selected item from the list, and add first empty `option` item. What should be done to make the first available option selected instead? Here is the markup:

```
%select{'ng-model' => 'search.device_type_id', 'ng-options' => 'type.id as type.product_name for type in device_types'}
%select{'ng-model' => 'device', 'ng-options' => 'device.serial_number for device in devices | filter:search'}
```

Comment: could you share more code or set up a plunker please

Comment: same problem bro, did you manage to find something?

Comment: @themis, I've done this with $watch inside the controller, see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
%select{'ng-model' => 'device', 'ng-options' => 'device.serial_number for device in devices | filter:search'}
```

to

```
%select{'ng-model' => 'device', 'ng-options' => 'device.serial_number for device in filtered_devices=(devices | filter:search)'}
```

and you will have filtered_devices in your scope to do with what ever you wish
specifically you can watch it and set the selected device when it changes

```
$scope.$watch('filtered_devices', function(value){
  if (filtered_devices) {
    $scope.device = filtered_devices[0];
  }
}, true);
```

so you don't have to filter again...

UPDATE:

After working with the model I suggested I discovered that is probably a bad idea to have a filter expression as the source for ng-options. I assume that the reason is that each time the filter is evaluated it returns a new collection and hence the diget cycle concludes that its is dirty and needs rebinding or whatever.

I am now using a different pattern in which I have a `filtered_items` collection in my `$scope` and I am updating it via "ng-change" on the filter input. so the `filtered_items` to which ng-options is bound does not change unless it actually needs to change...

Comment: Thank you, this way looks way better.

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed how to set default after filtering with directives, so did this with $watch within the controller, like this:

```
# View.haml

-# select itself
%select{'ng-model' => 'search.brand_id', 'ng-options' => 'brand.id as brand.name for brand in brands'}
%select{'ng-model' => 'search.device_type_id', 'ng-options' => 'type.id as type.product_name for type in device_types | filter:search.brand_id'}
%select{'ng-model' => 'device', 'ng-required' => 'true', 'ng-options' => 'device.serial_number for device in devices | filter:search'}

-# selected device
%input{'ng-model' => 'selectedDevice.id', type: 'text', disabled: true, placeholder: 'Select a device!'}
```

-

```
#Controller.js
$scope.$watch('search.device_type_id', function(value){
  var filtered_devices = $filter('filter')($scope.devices, $scope.search);
  if (filtered_devices) {
    $scope.device = filtered_devices[0];
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: hmm... is there no way to get the filtered list without applying the filter again?

Answer (score 0):

another solution which does not use `$watch` but uses `ng-change`

also added `debounce` so that it only calls `ng-change` after 1000 milliseconds

view

`%select{'ng-model' => 'device', 'ng-options' => 'device.serial_number for device in filtered_devices=(devices | filter:search)', 'ng-change' => 'updateDevices()', 'ng-model-options' => '{ debounce: 1000 }'}`

controller

```
$scope.filtered_devices = [];
$scope.updateDevices = function () {
    if ($scope.filtered_devices.length === 0) return;
    $scope.device = $scope.filtered_devices[0];
};
```